# The StackOverflowError occurs when I try to make JPQL JOIN query

Tags: java, join, spring-data-jpa, stack-overflow, jpql

I have the following entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "artist")
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="artist_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="artist_name", length = 2000)
    private String name;
    private String country;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artist", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    public Artist(String name, String country){
        this.name=name;
        this.country=country;
    }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int songId;
    @Column(name = "text", length = 65600)
    private String text;
    private Double rating;
    private String songName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id", nullable = false)
    public Artist artist;

    public Song(String text, Double rating, String songName, Artist artist) {
        this.text = text;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.songName = songName;
        this.artist = artist;
    }
}
```

I try to get all songs by artist name pattern:

**@Query("SELECT s FROM Song s WHERE s.artist.name LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%')")

List findByArtistsName(@Param("name") String name);**

and all artists by songs name patern:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Artist a JOIN FETCH a.songs s WHERE s.songName LIKE CONCAT('%',:pattern,'%')")
List<Artist> findBySong(@Param("pattern") String songName);
```

For this I am using that JPQL queries respectively. But both get me the same 
StackOverflowError.

```
> 
> 
>     Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.dtoa(FloatingDecimal.java:431)
> ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.access$100(FloatingDecimal.java:259)
> ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.getBinaryToASCIIConverter(FloatingDecimal.java:1785)
> ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.getBinaryToASCIIConverter(FloatingDecimal.java:1738)
> ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:70)
> ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.Double.toString(Double.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.Double.toString(Double.java:644) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at com.music.entity.Song.toString(Song.java:8) ~[classes/:na]
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
> ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at com.music.entity.Artist.toString(Artist.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at com.music.entity.Song.toString(Song.java:8) ~[classes/:na]
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
> ~[na:1.8.0_151]
```

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly being caused by your use of [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) and the `@Data` annotation which is a shortcut for these other Lombok annotations:

> @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter on all fields, and @Setter on all non-final fields, and @RequiredArgsConstructor

The `@ToString` annotation is automatically generating a `toString` method which includes all of your fields. The bottom of the stack trace points to a `toString` method call on a collection, if you follow the stack up you can spot the cycle which is causing the stack overflow:

`AbstractCollection.toString` -> `Song.toString` -> `Artist.toString` -> `AbstractCollection.toString` -> `Song.toString` ...

Your `Artist` entity holds a collection of `Song` entities which holds a reference to the `Artist` entity and so on. You can see how it gets caught in a loop when calling the `toString` method and eventually exhausts the stack frames / hits the limit.

Either remove the `@Data` annotation and only apply a subset or define your own `toString` method that avoids the loop.

Comment: Yes, It is realy true. Thank you, your answer is very helpful!